# How Have I Managed To Create A File As Root?

Tags: permissions, sudo

I have logged into a (RHEL) server and switched to the dev user via `sudo su - devuser`.

Everything I create is (naturally) owned as the devuser.

However, when I start this one (JBoss) process it manages to create a log file as root even though all the other files are created as the devuser.

The directory owned by root is created with `700` and the file as `644`.

How is this possible?

EDIT:
The JBoss process is started with the provided `standalone.sh`
https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-core/blob/11.0.x/core-feature-pack/src/main/resources/content/bin/standalone.sh which starts the JVM.

The log is created in the application server directory and not syslog:
`$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/logs/server.log`

Comment: Is the log file created via syslog (or the systemd equivalent)?

Comment: How do you start the jboss application? Where is the log file written and what's its name?